# Abstract characterization of group von Neumann algebra (II1 factor)

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

The group von Neumann algebra $L\Gamma$ is a factor if and only if the group $\Gamma$ is ICC (i.e. [infinite conjugacy class property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_conjugacy_class_property)). Moreover if $\Gamma$ is nontrivial then $L\Gamma$ is a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor.

*Question 0.1* (Sakai, Problem 4.4.10 [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0442701), 1971): Is every $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor a group von Neumann algebra?
*Answer* (Connes [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=377534), 1975): No, because there is a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor which is *not* anti-isomorphic to itself (whereas $L\Gamma$ is so).

*Question 0.2*: Is every $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor anti-isomorphic to itself a group von Neumann algebra?
*Answer* (Jones, [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=585235), 1980): No, because there is a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor which is anti-isomorphic to itself but without involutory antiautomorphisms (whereas $L\Gamma$ has so).

The answers for the next two questions were pointed out by Jiang's comments.

*Question 0.3* (Remark 5.7 in previous paper): Is a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor with an involutory antiautomorphism a group von Neumann algebra?
*Answer* (Ioana [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2813341), 2010): No, because there are $\mathrm{II}_1$ factors $M$ whose amplifications $M^t$ (with $t \neq 1$) admit an involutory antiautomorphism but are not group von Neumann algebras (see Corollary F, Corollary 10.1 and Remark 10.3).

*Question 0.4*: Is a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor with an involutory antiautomorphism stably isomormphic to a group von Neumann algebra (i.e. of the form $(L\Gamma)^t$)?
*Answer* (Boutonnet [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3077866), 2013): No, because there are crossed product von Neumann algebra $L^{\infty}(X,\mu) \rtimes_{\sigma} \Gamma$, with $σ$ a free ergodic pmp-action of an ICC group $Γ$ on a probability space $(X,μ)$, which are not stably isomorphic to a group von Neumann algebra.

**Question**: Is a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor with an involutory antiautomorphism stably isomorphic to a crossed product $A \rtimes G$, with $A$ an abelian von Neumann algebra and $G$ a group?

Recall that if the action of the group $G$ on the [abelian von Neumann algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_von_Neumann_algebra#Classification) $A$ is free then $A \rtimes G$ is a factor iff the action is ergodic. Now $A \rtimes G$ can be a factor without the action being free, for example when $A = \mathbb{C}$, because then $A \rtimes G = LG$.

*Remark*: The existence of a Kac algebra generating a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor not stably isomorphic to any $A⋊G$ (as above) would be very interesting.

The initial question and then Connes' paper were pointed out to me by [Keshab Chandra Bakshi](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/author.html?mrauthid=1197952).

Comment: The answer is negative as shown in Ioana's paper ``W*-superrigidity for Bernoulli actions of property (T) groups", see the discussion after corollary F there.

Comment: @Jiang: Thanks! After Sakai, Connes, Jones and now Ioana, what should be the next updated question? Because you posted your answer as a comment and not as an answer, I understand that you implicitly agree that I update the question according to your comment. I just updated the question. Please let me know whether you appreciate and whether you also know the answer.

Comment: This was answered negatively again by theorem D in Remi Boutonnet's paper "W^*-superrigidity of mixing Gaussian actions of rigid groups". Indeed, the point is to find W^*-superrigid actions such that (Thm C in Ioana's paper holds) and the crossed product vn alg from this action is NOT a group vn alg.

Comment: @Jiang: Thanks! Again you wrote your answer as a comment instead of an answer. Should I update the question again? It is up to you. The next updated question should be: Is a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor with an involutory antiautomorphism stably isomorphic to $LΓ$ or $L^{\infty}(X,\mu) \rtimes_{\sigma} \Gamma$, with $σ$ a pmp-action of an ICC group $Γ$ on a probability space $(X,μ)$, or more generally, stably isomorphic to $A⋊Γ$ with $A$ abelian von Neumann algebra? Do you also know the answer?

Comment: I do not know the answers.

Comment: It may be helpful to first find II$_1$ factors which are not stably isomorphic to any group factors or crossed products.

Comment: I think that references to Ioana and Boutonnet would make a good answer, and that further questions could be asked separately (what I upvoted was the original question because of its simplicity, not its latest version).

Comment: @YCor I let Jiang choose, what should I do?

Comment: @YCor The questions "Is a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor with an involutory antiautomorphism isomorphic to $LΓ$?" and "Is a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor with an involutory antiautomorphism stably isomorphic to $A⋊Γ$?" look almost as simple (to me) in their formulation. What is bothering you? "stably" or the cross-product?

Comment: The first one is simple. The second one is not exactly what you wrote (you wrote "t*o a group vN or a cross-product $L^\infty$... if not more generally stably iso...*"). I'm not familiar with the topic enough to have a judgement on the question and see if it has an immediate counterexample as a variation of the previous ones. And even if we eventually reach an open question, the first two are real questions and are worth a full question-and-reply post.

Comment: @YCor: You mean that you don't know whether there exist a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor of the form $A⋊Γ$ (as above) but not of the form $LΓ$  or $L^{\infty}(X,\mu) \rtimes_{\sigma} \Gamma$ (as above)? Interesting! It could be an open problem also! I need to check that, perhaps it will be a future MathOverflow post... This subject admits so many open problems which can be "easily" formulated, but so hard to solve!

Comment: But I'm really not a specialist in vN algebras. That a question has been solved recently doesn't make it off-topic. I upvoted the initial question because it was telling to me, and I think would be worth an answer by @Jiang (and, fine, along with its first variant solved by Boutonnet), maybe with just a reference, or with some further hints.