# Unusual crossed product constructions being factors

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be an [abelian von Neumann algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_von_Neumann_algebra) and $G$ a countable group acting on $A$. In the literature we meet usually two kinds of crossed product $A \rtimes G$ being a factor:

- if the action is (essentially) free then $A \rtimes G$ is a factor iff the action is ergodic,
- the group von Neumann algebra $LG$, which is $A \rtimes G$ with $A = \mathbb{C}$ (and trivial action), is a factor iff $G$ is [ICC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_conjugacy_class_property) (note that here the action is not free).

In this post we are interested in unusual crossed product factors, i.e. not of the above kinds.

**Question**: Take $A = \mathbb{C}^{\oplus n}$, what is a necessary and sufficient condition on $G$ and its action on $A$ for $A \rtimes G$ being a factor? Is it known for $n=2$?

*Example*: if $G$ is finite, $n = |G|$ and $A=\mathbb{C}^{\oplus n} = \ell^{\infty}(G)$ on which $G$ acts by translation then $A \rtimes G$ is a factor, isomorphic to $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$.

*Bonus question* (related to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/345844/34538)): Is there a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor $\mathbb{C}^{\oplus n} \rtimes G$ with $n>1$ which is not isomorphic to a group von Neumann algebra?

---

We fixed $A = \mathbb{C}^{\oplus n}$ for the question not being too broad, but all the results providing unusual crossed product constructions $A \rtimes G$ being factors, for any other $A$ (in particular atomless) are also welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following provides a necessary and sufficient condition for an arbitrary crossed product von Neumann algebra $L^\infty(X) \rtimes G$ to be a factor. As a corollary, I include a simpler criterion for actions that preserve a probability measure.

First note that a criterion for arbitrary actions necessarily has to refer to induced actions. Given an action $G \curvearrowright (X,\mu)$ of a countable group $G$ by nonsingular transformations (i.e. preserving sets of measure zero) of a standard probability space $(X,\mu)$, it may happen that there exists a subgroup $\Gamma < G$ and a $\Gamma$-invariant Borel set $Y \subset X$ such that, up to measure zero, the sets $(g \cdot Y)_{g \in G/\Gamma}$ form a partition of $X$. Then the crossed products satisfy
$$L^\infty(X) \rtimes G \cong B(\ell^2(G/\Gamma)) \overline{\otimes} (L^\infty(Y) \rtimes \Gamma) \; .$$
In particular, the crossed product for $G \curvearrowright X$ is a factor if and only if the crossed product for $\Gamma \curvearrowright Y$ is a factor.

Conversely, given any nonsingular action $\Gamma \curvearrowright Y$ and any embedding of $\Gamma$ into a larger group $G$, there is a natural action $G \curvearrowright X = G/\Gamma \times Y$ that is induced from $\Gamma \curvearrowright Y$.

These induced actions are characterized by the existence of a $G$-equivariant map $X \rightarrow G/\Gamma$. Note that if $\mu$ is an invariant probability measure, this forces $\Gamma$ to be a finite index subgroup of $G$; see the corollary below.

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a countable group and $G \curvearrowright (X,\mu)$ any action by nonsingular transformations of a standard probability space $(X,\mu)$. Then the following two conditions are equivalent.

(1) The crossed product $L^\infty(X) \rtimes G$ is a factor.

(2) The action $G \curvearrowright (X,\mu)$ is ergodic and whenever $G \curvearrowright X$ is induced from $\Gamma \curvearrowright Y$, the following holds: if $h \in \Gamma \setminus \{e\}$ acts trivially on $Y$, then $h$ has an infinite $\Gamma$-conjugacy class.

**Proof.** Write $A = L^\infty(X)$ and $M = A \rtimes G$. View $A \subset M$ and denote by $(u_g)_{g \in G}$ the canonical unitary operators in $M$.

(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2). If $F \in A$ is $G$-invariant, then $F$ belongs to the center of $M$ and hence $F$ is constant. So $G \curvearrowright (X,\mu)$ is ergodic. Assume that $G \curvearrowright (X,\mu)$ is induced from $\Gamma \curvearrowright Y$. Denote by $N \lhd \Gamma$ the normal subgroup that acts trivially on $Y$ and take $h \in N \setminus \{e\}$. If the $\Gamma$-conjugacy class $C$ of $h$ is finite, then $\sum_{g \in C} u_g$ defines a non scalar central element of the crossed product $L^\infty(Y) \rtimes \Gamma$. Then also $M$ would fail to be a factor. So $C$ must be infinite.

$\neg$ (1) $\Rightarrow$ $\neg$ (2). Assume that $M$ is not a factor and that $G \curvearrowright (X,\mu)$ is ergodic. We have to prove that $G \curvearrowright X$ is induced from $\Gamma \curvearrowright Y$ in such a way that there exists an element $h \in \Gamma \setminus \{e\}$ that acts trivially on $Y$ and that has a finite $\Gamma$-conjugacy class.

Let $T$ be a non scalar element in the center of $M$. Denote by $E : M \rightarrow A$ the normal conditional expectation satisfying $E(u_g) = 0$ for all $g \in G \setminus \{e\}$. Then, $E(T)$ is $G$-invariant and thus scalar. Replacing $T$ by $T - E(T)$, we may thus assume that $T$ is a central element with $E(T) = 0$ and $T \neq 0$.

View $M$ as the algebra of bounded measurable functions $F : X \rightarrow B(\ell^2(G))$ satisfying $T(g \cdot x) = \rho_g T(x) \rho_g^*$ for all $g \in G$ and a.e. $x \in X$. Here $\rho$ is the right regular representation of $G$. We then associate to $T$ the function
$$f : X \rightarrow \ell^2(G) : f(x) = T(x) \delta_e \; .$$
Since $T(x) \delta_h = \rho_h f(h^{-1} \cdot x)$, we get that $f$ is not a.e. zero. Since $E(T) = 0$, we have $f(x) \in \ell^2(G \setminus \{e\})$. The fact that $T$ is central translates to the following two properties for the function $f$.

- The fact that $T$ commutes with the unitary operators $u_g$ translates to: $f(g \cdot x) = \text{Ad}(g) f(x)$ for all $g \in G$ and a.e. $x \in X$.
- The fact that $T$ commutes with $A$ translates to: if $f(x)(h) \neq 0$, then $h \cdot x = x$.

Define the measurable function
$$S : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : S(x) = \max \{ |f(x)(h)| \mid h \in G \} \; .$$
This is well defined because $f(x) \in \ell^2(G)$. Since $S$ is $G$-invariant, it follows that $S$ is constant a.e. Also, $S$ is not a.e. zero. So we find $0 < s < \infty$ such that $S(x) =s$ for a.e. $x \in X$. For every $x \in X$, denote by $R(x) \subset G$ the finite subset given by
$$R(x) = \{h \in G \mid |f(x)(h)| = s\} \; .$$
We have $R(g \cdot x) = g R(x) g^{-1}$. Also, $R(x) \neq \emptyset$ and $R(x) \subset G \setminus \{e\}$ for a.e. $x \in X$. There are only countably many finite subsets of $G$. So we can fix a nonempty finite subset $C \subset G \setminus \{e\}$ such that the set
$$Y = \{x \in X \mid R(x) = C\}$$
has positive measure. When $g \in G$, the set $g \cdot Y \cap Y$ has positive measure if and only if $g C g^{-1} = C$. Defining the subgroup $\Gamma < G$ by
$$\Gamma = \{g \in G \mid g C g^{-1} = C\} \; ,$$
it follows that $G \curvearrowright X$ is induced from $\Gamma \curvearrowright Y$. When $g \in C$ and $x \in Y$, we have $|f(x)(g)| = s > 0$ so that $g \cdot x = x$. In particular, $R(g \cdot x) = R(x)$, so that $gCg^{-1} = C$ and $g \in \Gamma$. We conclude that $C$ is a finite subset of $\Gamma \setminus \{e\}$ that is invariant under $\Gamma$-conjugation and that all elements of $C$ act trivially on $Y$. So, $\neg 2$ holds.

**Corollary.** Let $G$ be a countable group and $G \curvearrowright (X,\mu)$ any action by $\mu$-preserving transformations of a standard probability space $(X,\mu)$. Then the following two conditions are equivalent.

(1) The crossed product $L^\infty(X) \rtimes G$ is a factor.

(2) The action $G \curvearrowright (X,\mu)$ is ergodic and if $g \in G \setminus \{e\}$ is such that $\{x \in X \mid g \cdot x = x\}$ has positive measure, then $g$ has an infinite conjugacy class.

**Proof.** (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1). Assume that $G \curvearrowright X$ is induced from $\Gamma \curvearrowright Y$ and that $g \in \Gamma \setminus \{e\}$ acts trivially on $Y$. By the theorem above, it suffices to prove that $g$ has an infinite $\Gamma$-conjugacy class. Since $\mu$ is a $G$-invariant probability measure, $\Gamma < G$ has finite index. It thus suffices to prove that $g$ has an infinite $G$-conjugacy class. Since $g$ fixes all points of $Y$, this is indeed the case by the assumption in (2).

$\neg$ (2) $\Rightarrow$ $\neg$ (1). Assume that $g_0 \in G \setminus \{e\}$ fixes all points in a subset of $X$ of positive measure and that the $G$-conjugacy class $C$ of $g_0$ is finite. We prove that the second condition in the theorem above does not hold. Since $C$ is finite and since $g_0 \in C$ fixes all points in a set of positive measure, we can choose a maximal subset $C_0 \subset C$ containing $g_0$ and having the property that
$$Y := \{x \in X \mid h \cdot x = x \;\;\text{for all $h \in C_0$}\;\}$$
has positive measure. When $g \in G$ and $x \in g \cdot Y \cap Y$, we have that $h \cdot x = x$ for all $h \in C_0 \cup g C_0 g^{-1} \subset C$. By the maximality of $C_0$ we conclude that $g \cdot Y \cap Y$ has positive measure if and only if $gC_0 g^{-1} = C_0$ if and only if $g \cdot Y = Y$. Defining
$$\Gamma = \{g \in G \mid gC_0 g^{-1} = C_0\} \; ,$$
we find that $G \curvearrowright X$ is induced from $\Gamma \curvearrowright Y$. By construction, $C_0 \subset \Gamma \setminus \{e\}$ is a finite set of elements that act trivially on $Y$ and $C_0$ is invariant under conjugation by $\Gamma$. So the second condition in the theorem above does not hold and the corollary is proven.

Comment: Really excellent answer.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! Thanks for your great answer. Here are my first comments: at the end of the 2nd paragraph of the 1st proof, finite should be infinite. You removed the use of normal subgroup $N$ in the statement of the theorem but not from its proof (2nd and last paragraph) and from the corollary's proof (1st and last paragraph); it should also be removed from there (if I'm not mistaken). In the 3rd paragraph of the 1st proof you wrote << $E(T)$ is $G$-invariant and thus scalar >> so I guess you assume that the action is ergodic to then prove the negation of the 2nd part of (2), right?

Comment: Thank you, Sébastien. I corrected the typo "finite -> infinite" and I added a few sentences with extra details for the argument.

Answer (score 2):

For a countable discrete group $G$, the crossed product $L^\infty(X,\mu)\rtimes G$ for a nonsingular action is a factor if

1. the action is ergodic and
2. almost all stabilisers  $G_x:=\mathop{\mathrm{Stab}}(x)$ are i.c.c.

*Proof.* 
Suppose the action is ergodic and almost all $G_x$ are i.c.c., and let $k$ be a central element in $L^\infty(X)\rtimes G$. Then $k$ has a (unique) “Fourier series” $k = \sum_{g\in G} k_g u_g$. As $k$ commutes with every $f\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$, we have $f\cdot k_g = \alpha_g(f)k_g$ for all $f$, so $\mathop{\mathrm{supp}} k_g \subset \{x\in X\mid g\in G_x\}$, so $k$ is “supported in the bundle of stabilisers”.

Now, let $h_n\colon X\to G$ be measurable functions such that $G_x = \{h_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ for almost every $x\in X$ and let $b_n\colon x\mapsto \chi_{\mathop{\mathrm{supp}}h_n}(x)\cdot h_n(x)$. Now, $b_n \in L^\infty(X)\rtimes G$, and so have to commute with $k$. A little calculation then shows that for a conull subset $Y_n\subset X$ we then have that $k_{h_n(x)gh_n(x)^{-1}}(x) = k_g(x)$ for all $g\in G$. Intersecting $Y_n$'s, we get that on a conull subset $k$ is constant on conjugacy classes. Since $G_x$ is i.c.c., $k_g = 0$ for $g\neq 1$.

In the original version of my answer I claimed that the converse is also true; however, my original answer contained a mistake. Still, one can say a lot:

For a countable discrete group $G$, the crossed product $L^\infty(X,\mu)\rtimes G$ for a nonsingular action being a factor implies that the action is ergodic. Moreover, if additionally one of the following is satisfied:

- the FC-centre $FC(G_x)$ is finite for a.e. $x\in X$ or
- $X$ is finite,

then almost all stabilisers  $G_x:=\mathop{\mathrm{Stab}}(x)$ are i.c.c. (More precise conditions are discussed in the proof below.)

*Proof.*

If the action is not ergodic, $\chi_B$ for an invariant measurable subset $B\subset X$ is in the centre.

Suppose the action is ergodic but $G_x$ is not i.c.c. on a subset of positive measure; by ergodicity, $G_x$ is not i.c.c. for almost every $x\in X$.

Let $Z_x:= \mathscr Z(L(G_x))$ be the centre of the von Neumann algebra of $G_x$. By assumption, it is nontrivial for a.e. $x\in X$. Consider the direct integral
$$
Z:=\int^\oplus_X Z_x\, d\mu(x)\subseteq L^\infty(X)\rtimes G.
$$
It is a $G$-invariant (w.r.t. conjugation action) abelian von Neumann subalgebra containing $L^\infty(X)$. The $G$-equivariant inclusion $L^\infty(X)$ corresponds to a factor map $(\widehat Z,\nu) \to (X,\mu)$, where $\widehat Z$ is the spectrum of $Z$. The fibres of this map are canonically identified with $(\widehat{Z_x},\nu_x)$, with the marginal measures $\nu_x$ canonically induced by the trace on $L(G_x)$.

By ergodicity the type of $(\widehat{Z_x},\nu_x)$ is the same a.e., and we get the following possibilities for the types of $(Z_x,\nu_x)$:

1. with an atomic and a nonatomic part
2. finite
3. countably infinite
4. atomless.

In the first case the element $x\mapsto z_x$, where $z_x\in Z_x$ is the projection onto the atomic part is a nontrivial central element. In the second case the FC-centre of $G_x$ is a.e. finite, so the element $x\mapsto \sum_{g\in FC(G_x)} g$ is nontrivial and central. In the third case, the element $x\mapsto z_x$, where $z_x\in Z_x$ is the projection onto the sum of the biggest atoms is central and non-trivial (as the subset of $Z$ consisting of the biggest atoms in each $Z_x$ is clearly invariant).

Finally, if $X$ is finite, then by ergodicity $X$ can be identified with $G/S$, and by assumption $S$ is not i.c.c. Let $C\subset S$ be a non-trivial finite $S$-conjugacy class; the element $gx\mapsto \sum_{c\in C} gcg^{-1}$ of the von Neumann algebra is well-defined, nontrivial and central.

P.S. It was pointed out by Stefaan Vaes that $L^\infty(X)\rtimes G$ can be a factor for an action with non-i.c.c. stabiliser; in fact, one cannot say anything about the factoriality of the crossed product by looking only at the  structure of stabilisers.

Comment: Thanks! Should $(X,\mu)$ be nonatomic? Can $G$ be locally compact? Is your result in the literature? Where?

Comment: Nonatomicity is not required. For locally compact groups the situation, I believe, is more difficult because even to determine whether $LG$ is a factor is not that easy (see, for instance, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.07793.pdf, Theorem E (7.2) and its proof).

For the discrete p.m.p. case, the result can be found, for instance, in the thesis of Rahel Brugger (Lemma 2.1.10): https://ediss.uni-goettingen.de/bitstream/handle/11858/00-1735-0000-002E-E3D5-B/Dissertation_Brugger.pdf?sequence=1' there it's written down and proven in the language of groupoids.

Comment: Very interesting! It is suprising that such a general result do not appear in Takesaki's books, but only last year. Are you sure that it does not appear before (in the language of groups)? The result of Sven Raum is also very interesting, it is restricted to his condition (∗), but is it conjectured without (∗)?

Comment: Well, I'm not 100 % sure this really _never_ appeared anywhere else (in case of discrete group actions), but at least standard sources indeed do not seem to contain it. On the other hand, I think, the proof is a more-or-less straightforward merger of the two extreme cases...

Concerning locally compact groups: unfortunately I'm no expert at all in their von Neumann algebras, so I don't quite know what is expected there.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Which aspect of the answer do you exactly consider problematic?

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: Your comment led me to check the argument and it indeed contained a mistake; thanks a lot for expressing your doubt. I could fill the gap in many cases, but one case is still missing (see the updated version).

Comment: Stefaan just posted an answer.